# matlab: quick function that can produce NaN if x > 1

Tags: matlab, function, nan

I am looking for a one-line function `f = @(x) {something}` that produces NaN if x >= 1, and either 0 or 1 if x < 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha, I got it:

```
f = @(x) 0./(x<1)
```

yields 0 for x < 1 and NaN for x>=1.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a modification of Jason's solution that works for arrays. Note that recent versions of MATLAB do not throw divide-by-zero warnings.

```
>> f = @(x) zeros(size(x)) ./ (x < 1)

f = 

    @(x)zeros(size(x))./(x<1)

>> f(0:.3:2)

ans =

     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**Update**: a coworker pointed out to me that Jason's original answer works just fine for arrays.

```
>> f = @(x) 0./(x<1)

f = 

    @(x)0./(x<1)

>> f(0:.3:2)

ans =

     0     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Good to know that the newer versions of MATLAB no longer throw DBZ warnings by default. That was always kinda annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that won't risk throwing any divide-by-zero warnings, since it doesn't involve any division (just the functions [ONES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ones.html) and [NAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html)):

```
f = @(x) [ones(x < 1) nan(x >= 1)];
```

**EDIT:** The above solution is made for scalar inputs. If a vectorized solution is needed (which isn't 100% clear from the question) then you could modify `f` like so:

```
f = @(x) arrayfun(@(y) [ones(y < 1) nan(y >= 1)],x);
```

Or apply [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) when calling the first version of the function `f`:

```
y = arrayfun(f,x);
```

Comment: neat, but it fails for vector input.

Comment: @Jonas: True, although it wasn't apparent from the question that a vectorized solution was required. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Excellent! Now I can give +1 for the most clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less obvious solution (vectorized nonetheless):

```
f = @(x) subsasgn(zeros(size(x)), struct('type','()','subs',{{x>=1}}), nan) + 0
```

Basically its equivalent to:

```
function v = f(x)
    v = zeros(size(x));
    v( x>=1 ) = nan;
```

The `+0` at the end is to always force an output, even if `f` called with no output arguments (returned in `ans`). Example:

```
>> f(-2:2)
ans =
     0     0     0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: no need for `find`. I like this function best, since it is the cleanest implementation that will also work for arrays.